# Metric underlines in Microstrategy

Tags: reporting-services, microstrategy

How to avoid underline in metrics in microstrategy documents.
For example - if I have a revenue metric it is underlined in all documents for all metrics.

Comment: it's the header which is underlined or the metric values?

Comment: all metrics values are underlined when they are used as selectors, looks like its a default feature of microstrategy. Is there any fix for this? please let me know

Answer (score 0):

The underline under the values when a column in a Microstrategy grid is used a selector is an out of the box feature. The value used as selector is rendered on the HTML page as an hyperlink and displayed with an underline.

The only why to modify this behavior, at least that I found, is to customize the CSS so that links appear without the underscore.

This is a small SDK customization for MicroStrategy, but still it requires a bit of advanced knowledge of the MicroStrategy components.

If you are interested you can start from here:

[Cascading Style Sheet (CSS) Files](https://lw.microstrategy.com/msdz/MSDL/900/docs/DeveloperLibrary.htm#CU_CSS_Files.htm)

[Customizing CSS Files](https://lw.microstrategy.com/msdz/MSDL/900/docs/CU_CSS_customizing_CSS.htm)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Your information is very help full

Answer (score 0):

There is option for formatting for metrices in the document. You can right-click on the metric, choose formatting and choose not to underline the particular metric.

Also, in the metric itself (accessed from developer) has the options for various formatting. You can change from there.